# Dynamic SQL to find multiple levels of hierarchical substance in SAP

Tags: sql, t-sql, dynamic-programming

Problem statement : I have parent substance (BE8588). I need to find out substances across all the levels this parent element can be related to. My query currently is giving only until the first level substance, I need to repeat the logic and extend across all the levels .
[image]

Code snip :
'''

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmp_EhsCompositionSpec
SELECT  DISTINCT   Sub.ESTRH_SubID ParentSubID
                  ,sub.ESTVA_RECNROOT Parent_RecnRoot 
                  ,sub.ESTVP_RECNCMP
INTO #tmp_EhsCompositionSpec
     
FROM 
( 
SELECT           rh.SUBID ESTRH_SubID 
                ,vp.RECNCMP ESTVP_RECNCMP               
                ,VA.RECNROOT ESTVA_RECNROOT                                                 
        FROM  TableA rh where rh.SUBID = 'BE8588'
) sub  

-- Create child components 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmp_child_Components
Select distinct    tmp.ParentSubID 
                  ,der.SUBID
INTO #tmp_child_Components 
FROM #tmp_EhsCompositionSpec tmp 
left outer join 
   ( Select rh.subid 
           , rh.RECNROOT Child_RecnRoot
       FROM TableB Rh
      INNER JOIN tableC  Ri on rh.RECN = ri.RECNROOT
      ) der on der.Child_RecnRoot = tmp.ESTVP_RECNCMP

      -- Union of above 2 results 
SELECT RecipeId , Component_Substance 
FROM 
( 

SELECT ParentSubID RecipeId,ParentSubID Component_Substance from #tmp_EhsCompositionSpec 
union 
SELECT ParentSubID , SUBID from #tmp_child_Components 
) u
```

'''
Above query gives me only the first level of nested records, I need to repeat the logic if there are any substances starting  with 'BE' and load into a new column called level2Subs and so on.

Comment: any reference posts to guide me will also help.

Comment: look into "recursive CTE"